# How to change the database which is used to store liferay content?

Tags: mysql, database, glassfish, liferay

I have a glassfish server built with company default script. Then I have Liferay installed upon it. Liferay uses some predefined database to store the content on the pages it shows. It is a company shared database don't know where. How could I connect my liferay to a local clean database?

My setup is a Glassfish with Liferay, the DatabaseI use is MySQL.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I got some instructions from working mate. I'll post the solution here when inventing first how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all explained here:

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Database+Configuration

Comment: With these instructions I got a problem on ping to the database. It could be solved with this link: http://www.innoq.com/blog/gs/2007/10/howto_get_jsasglassfish_with_m.html